# Nested Scenes in React Native with React-Native-Router-Flux

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-native-router-flux

I'm using React-Native-Router-Flux (V. 3.37) to build an Android app and I'm trying to create nested scenes. Using the DefaultRenderer element I have been able to create a single nested scene, but I'd like there to be multiple and to be able to navigate through them.

My index.android.js looks something like this (within a Router and Scene key="root" element).

```
<Scene
   key="outer"
   component={Outer}
   title="Outer"
   initial
   hideNavBar
 >
    <Scene
      key="inner1"
      component={Inner1}
      title="Inner1"
      hideNavBar
    />
    <Scene
      key="inner2"
      component={Inner2}
      title="Inner2"
      hideNavBar
     />
</Scene>
```

The Outer component is something like this:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.smallContainer}>
      <DefaultRenderer 
         navigationState={this.props.children[0]}
         onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate}
      />
   </View>
</View>
```

Like this the Inner1 component will be properly nested within the smallContainer view in the Outer component. But I have no clue how to navigate to Inner2. If I simply hard code this.props.children[1] as the navigationState, it tells me "navigationState and onNavigate property should be not null."

If I put a TouchableHighlight in Inner1 with onPress={Actions.inner2}, it simply does nothing.

My instinct tells me that the answer lies with the onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate} attribute within the DefaultRenderer element in the Outer component, but I've been unable to find any information about that. I just copied the DefaultRenderer element from deep inside the example docs of React-Native-Router-Flux.

I've also looked into React-Native-Simple-Router, React-Native-Router, and React-Router-Native, but none of them were clearly any better.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue. It doesn't look like the devs at react-router-flux have got a proper solution to this issue yet. Currently you have to first navigate to the parent component then navigate to it's children from there...

```
<Scene>
  <Scene key="scene1">
    <Scene key="scene2" hideNavBar component={Scene2}/>
  </Scene>
  <Scene key="scene3">
    <Scene key="scene4" hideNavBar component={Scene4}/>
    <Scene key="scene5" hideNavBar component={Scene5}/>
    <Scene key="scene6" hideNavBar component={Scene6}/>
  </Scene>
</Scene>
```

Say you're at `scene2` you'd have to do the following to get to `scene4`:

```js
Actions.scene3()
Actions.scene4()
```

This solution was copied from https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1801#issuecomment-307559086

This is a pretty expensive way of doing it because you have to navigate to two components rather than just one but it looks like the only way of doing it for now.